# SQLite: Delete Rule Capabilities With Reflexive Joins?

Tags: sqlite

I am attempting to use foreign key support in SQLite to maintain referential integrity on a single-table database that has a reflexive join.

e.g.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

create table tree (
  objectId text unique not null,
  parentObjectID text,
  foreign key (parentObjectID) references tree(parentObjectID) on delete cascade
)
```

The behavior that I am hoping for is that when a parent row is deleted, its children and their children are deleted as well.

However, when I attempt to delete the root row (where the expected behavior would be that every other row in the database is also deleted), I get this error:

```
sqlite> delete from tree where objectid = '0';
Error: foreign key mismatch
```

Are my expectations out of whack with with SQLite foreign key support (and delete behaviors) can provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple, your FK on `parentObjectId` references `parentObjectId` rather than `objectId` and SQLite doesn't detect this bit of confusion until you try to use the table. If your FK is defined like this:

```
foreign key (parentObjectID) references tree(objectID) on delete cascade
```

From the [fine manual](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes):

> So, in other words, misconfigured foreign key constraints that require looking at both the child and parent are DML errors. The English language error message for foreign key DML errors is usually "foreign key mismatch" but can also be "no such table" if the parent table does not exist. Foreign key DML errors are may be reported if:
>
> - The parent table does not exist, or
> - The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint do not exist, or
> - The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint are not the primary key of the parent table and are not subject to a unique
>     constraint using collating sequence specified in the CREATE TABLE, or
> - The child table references the primary key of the parent without specifying the primary key columns and the number of primary key
>     columns in the parent do not match the number of child key columns.

The third point would seem to apply here since `parentObjectId` is neither a PK nor constrained to be unique so that's why you don't see an error until you try to modify the table's content (i.e. use a DML statement rather than a DDL statement).

Comment: LOL... Ouch. Well, it's good to have a second set of eyes. I wonder how long it would have taken me to see that one... Sigh. Thank you!

Comment: Took me awhile to spot it too even though it was hiding in plain site.

Comment: I am seeing the behavior that I anticipated now. If the "root" row is deleted, the delete rules cascade to produce an empty table.